# functions with a subclass parameter

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

So I got a Class Person and it contains age, sex, name (and an primary key ID).
I then got 2 subclasses of person:

```
Teacher(Class(French, math, english etc etc), Sick(boolean))

student(Class(French, math, english etc etc), Sick(boolean)) 
//so these 2 got the same 5 fields.
```

Now I want to make 1 method that can create all 2 of them. (in practice there even more but oke for the question I ll just use these 2)

This is what I am thinking of:

```
public Person CreateNewPerson (int age, boolean sex, string name, int class, boolean sick, HELP HERE plz OFTYPE<TEACHER OR STUDENT>)
{
    var Person1 = new Person { Age = age, Sex = sex, ....... };
    // but now to return it as the correct type I got no clue what todo
    return (OFTYPE)Person1; // ofc this doesn t work but I hope you understand the problem here
}
```

Hope someone is able to help me out here, because atm I am making a seperate `CreateNewTeacher`, `CreateNewStudent` etc etc for every subclass I got.(And I got like 5 of them ^^)

Thanks in advance!

PS: They are saved in different tables later, I don t want them all in the same class, because I know I can go and add like a boolean at person: `IsPersonChild` and then true or flase but na h

Comment: not realy I am working on a project, and we are atm making a WCF service that gets its data from a EF model however we used inheritance on our objects so they got never the same ID. The project I am doing this for is smartp1ck(dot)com. I just wrote this quickly to explain my problem I must admit it looks like homework ^^.

Comment: Just wondering - your classes differ only by name, or they have different behavior?

Comment: They do have different functions and also they are linked with other tables (in the database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggested class setup:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
}

public class Student : Person
{
}

public static class PersonFactory
{
    public static T MakePerson<T>(string name) where T: Person, new()
    {
        T person = new T {Name = name};
        return person;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Teacher teacher = PersonFactory.MakePerson<Teacher>("Mrs. Smith");

Student student = PersonFactory.MakePerson<Student>("Johnny");
```

Comment: Note: Using a factory can even handle if the subclasses had different parameters, by checking `if(typeof(T) == typeof(Teacher)`

Comment: Oke thanks this solved it, Also the comment with typeof was needed since I got indeed subclasses with different parameters thx alot. I ll implement this later in my WCF service thx

Answer (score 1):

Use could use generics like this:

```
public T CreateNewPerson<T> (int age, boolean sex, string name, int class, boolean sick) where T : Person, new()
{
    var Person1 = new T { Age = age, Sex = sex, ....... };
    return Person1; 
}
```